# Is there a way to display legend's data over the chart in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I've created a pie chart using the chart.js and react-chartjs-2 library but I was wondering if there is a way to display the data over the chart component and not as a tooltip while hovering about each area of the pie chart

What I wanted to do is display the data related to each area over itself, like on top of it.

Comment: This can be done with `chartjs-plugin-datalabels` as explained here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59403435/2358409 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/67623057/2358409

Answer (score -1):

The options can be added while creating new chart

```
var pieChart = new Chart(canvas, {
type: "pie",
data: data,
options: {
     legend: {
        display: true,
        position : 'top'
     },
     tooltips: {
        enabled: false
     }
}
});
```

Comment: First this syntax you are using is outdated and incorrect, also the legend is on by default and this does not show the data of the chart above it, just the labels

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't work. I wanted it to display over each slice.